# New database in MonetDB with windows 7 64 bits

Tags: windows, monetdb

I am using the demo database, but would like to create a new database.

How do I create a new database in MonetDB with windows 64 bits?

Comment: in my opinion, the easiest way to set up a new monetdb server on windows is through R.  step by step instructions here  https://github.com/ajdamico/asdfree/tree/master/MonetDB

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are starting MonetDB through the provided **MSQLserver.bat** (which is called from the *"MonetDB SQL Server"* application). If you take a look in it, you will see that it will call in turn **M5server.bat** (You can find all files in your installation directory)

In **M5Server.bat** you will find on line 36 the setting of the variable MONETDBFARM. This variable will later on be used to call *mserver5.exe* (the actual database server). If you need a second database - it is easiest to make a copy of the **M5server.bat** file, and change the name of the MONETDBFARM. For instance:

```
set MONETDBFARM="--dbpath=%MONETDBDIR%\dbfarm\myowndb"
```

This will make sure that whenever you run the .bat file the *myowndb* database will be started.

Of course you could also call *mserver5.exe* yourself with the correct parameters, but as this batch file is already taking care of thing for you, it is easiest to just make a copy and use that.